# A list of, list of ObservableCollection<Image> comes up null when looping through it

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, observablecollection

I have a collection of collection that's setup like the following.

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Image>> _Documents_CompleteClaims= new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Image>>();
```

And I'm adding a collection to the list like this:

```
this._Documents_CompleteClaims.Add(this._Documents_NewClaimList);
```

<strike>When I try to loop through the collection, it shows up null. The collection has an object:</strike>

[image]

But the collection count shows 0.

[image]

I used this same method a while back, but with List instead of ObservableCollection. It worked fine before. Any ideas why observable collections aren't working? Or am I just overlooking something silly?

So I misdiagnosed the issue. The problem is that the collection in the collection has no items.

This is how I was adding the collection to the list of collections:

```
this._Documents_CompleteClaims.Add(this._Documents_NewClaimList); //Add claim to completed list
this._Documents_NewClaimList.Clear(); //Clear out the claim list so we can start a new claim
```

I confirmed that the **_Documents_NewClaimList** collection had items. I thought I could add that collection to the collection of collections and then clear the **_Documents_NewClaimList** collection. But if I comment it out the .Clear() line, it works just fine. So I guess I'll need to remove the items in a different way. Maybe I can add the items to a temporary collection, add that temp collection to the collection of collections, and then clear the old collection.

Comment: The code you posted should work. Could you post a small, but complete sample code that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: you are looking at the properties of 2 different collections.  The first is _Documents_CompleteClaims, the next is the collection it contains.  Nowhere do you show adding anything to that collection. You are adding an empty collection to a collection of collections.  Nowhere do you show adding an actual image to this._Documents_NewClaimList

Comment: @BrianRudolph Brian, when I add the collection to the collection, it's not empty. It has items. I don't know why those items aren't staying in the child collection. I'll update my post with how I'm adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with what you've posted.  You do *not* encounter null, that was the wrong diagnosis.  You've got a collection of collections, it contains one item.  Which is a collection that's empty.  I don't doubt that's a bug, but it is not a bug in the code you've posted.

Best to focus on the code that is supposed to add Image objects to that empty collection.

Comment: Yeah. The collection in the collection has no items. Which is strange, because I walked through it and it had items prior to adding it to the main collection. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer. Ultimately, calling .Clear() on my collection after adding that collection to the collection of collections, caused the issue. I solved it by adding the items to a temporary list prior to clearing and then adding that temporary list to the collection of collections.